# Landau levels in graphene - unbounded from below spectrum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, electronic-band-theory, quantum-hall-effect, graphene

Considering the case of monolayer graphene in a perpendicular magnetic field arises LL in it. The final spectrum is given by
$$
\epsilon_n=\mathrm{sign}(n)\hbar\omega\sqrt{|n|}
$$
where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. (For example, in this [paper](https://p303.zlibcdn.com/dtoken/9537654c8dc47eb4ec074afc72c15b8e) at eq. (11))

Each level in 8-fold degenerated (valley, sublattice and spin) but that's not important.

What bothering me the most is that the spectrum **is unbounded from below**, it does not have a ground state in a sense. What does it mean? How can we occupied any finite LL (and the 0th in particular)? How can one see (a priori, arising from the equations) that the Fermi energy sits at $\epsilon=0$?

Comment: It's unbounded because this spectrum is obtained using the Dirac description of the low-energy spectrum of the graphene, which is already unbounded when $B=0$. What it means is that the result is only valid for energies much smaller than the band width. Otherwise the spectrum will deviate significantly.

Comment: Okay, yes, that's make sense, but how can you see that the occupation is naturally going around $\epsilon=0$?(is it?)

Comment: If you count the number of electrons in graphene, it is naturally half filling, meaning the Fermi energy is at the Dirac point.